# How to merge multiple .HDF5 files in single file in Octave

Tags: octave, cdo-climate, grads

I have multiple .HDF5 files of 30 min IMERG precipitation data for a month (July 2022) in a folder having same shape.

Is there a way to merge multiple files in a single file through Octave or any other source?

If not the how to open multiple files at once and access the data within the files.
I have tried this but getting an error

```
data = data_from_multiple_HDF5_files('F:\Task_3_IMERG\HDF5_Practice', '*.HDF5' )
```

> error: 'data_from_multiple_HDF5_files' undefined near line 1, column 1

Comment: The error is because `data_from_multiple_HDF5_files` is not a real function. Where did you get this from?

Comment: I usually convert them to netcdf and then use CDO to merge...

Comment: Adrian Tompkins https://stackoverflow.com/users/6068294/adrian-tompkins
 Please tell me how to convert HDF5 files to netcdf. It would be helpful.